# Wifi is Hard-Blocked and Ethernet connection fails - [Ubuntu 14.04] - [Asus B43S-XH51]

Tags: wireless, network-manager, asus, ethernet, iwlwifi

I was just using this laptop yesterday on ethernet and a few days ago on wifi. I've never had a problem with this computer and wifi.

I currently only have Ubuntu 14.04 installed - no dual-boot with Windows anymore.

Sometimes the wifi reads as not being accessible due to a hardware switch, other times it just says that it's disabled.

I have also tried Fn-f2, and it does change the output of *rfkill list all*, but the Wifi stays constant as hard-blocked.

***rfkill list all***

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

***ifconfig***

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:04:4a:07:25  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7d00000-f7d20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:231 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:17265 (17.2 KB)  TX bytes:17265 (17.2 KB)
```

***interfaces***

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

***iwlwifi.conf***

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

***nm-tool***

```
    NetworkManager Tool

    State: disconnected

    - Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
      Type:              802.11 WiFi
      Driver:            iwlwifi
      State:             unavailable
      Default:           no
      HW Address:        88:53:2E:55:DB:6A

      Capabilities:

      Wireless Properties
        WEP Encryption:  yes
        WPA Encryption:  yes
        WPA2 Encryption: yes

      Wireless Access Points 


    - Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
      Type:              Wired
      Driver:            e1000e
      State:             unavailable
      Default:           no
      HW Address:        F4:6D:04:4A:07:25

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

***lspci***

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
    00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
    00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
    00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
    00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
    00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
    00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
    00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
    00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
    00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
    01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Caicos HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6400 Series]
    03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
    06:00.0 USB controller: Fresco Logic FL1000G USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of: lsmod | grep asus Thanks.